# Update label of MasterPage from content page when there is no ScriptManager in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager

I had not used `ScriptManager` on my MasterPage as it was not required when I started developing the project, so I have an individual `ScriptManager` and `UpdatePanel` for each content page.

In the MasterPage now I've added a label which shows the current system time, and my client wants it to change asynchronously and give a live clock feeling. Can I change the label text in the master page from the content page using `Timer`? So far I'm unable to achieve this, as I can't use an `UpdatePanel` also in the MasterPage because there is no `ScriptManager` tag.

So is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you can get the Master page instance using `((YourMasterClass)this.Master).Whatever()`, but the best solution would be adding a ScriptManager to the Master, removing it from the content pages and implementing this clock at the Master page only. The clock is a Master's responsability.

Comment: Why you don't use plain javascript on master page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ Yuriy Rozhovetskiy, From your suggestion i had created a simple javascript and called that javascript on Master page body on load and its working fine. Please find code below which may help to some one who also have same requirement:-

Javascript Function:-

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    function clock(){ 
      var d = new Date(); 
      var h = d.getHours(); 
      var m = d.getMinutes(); 
      var s = d.getSeconds(); 
      $('#clock').html(h+"<span class='colon'>:</span>"+m+"<span class='colon'>:</span>"+s); 
    //  $('.colon').fadeTo(1000, .2); 
      setTimeout(clock, 1000); 
    }
```

`<body onload="clock()">`

Added this to display clock on master page.

```
<span id="clock" style="font-family:Calibri;color:White;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;"></span>
```